# How can I use Pandera to check a Pandas column that might have floats or ints

Tags: dataframe, types, schema, union, pandera

I am trying to set up a DataFrameSchema in Pandera. The catch is that one of the columns of data may be a float or an int, depending on what data source was used to create the dataframe. Is there a way to set up a check on such a column? This code failed:

```
import pandera as pa
from pandera.typing import DataFrame, Series
from datetime import datetime
import pandas as pd

class IngestSchema(pa.SchemaModel):
    column_header: Series[float | int] = pa.Field(alias = 'MY HEADER')
```

Other things I've tried:

```
from typing import Union
float_int = Union[float, int]
```

But pandera does not recognize that union as a datatype. Is there any way to set up such a schema?

Answer (score 2):

Digging into their [docs](https://pandera.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/generated/pandera.dtypes.is_numeric.html) they have a `is_numeric` [which checks if its a _Number datatype](https://github.com/unionai-oss/pandera/blob/8413a3a9bf36a38dd05ab1c1a67a8cbaccdf7323/pandera/dtypes.py#L577-L579). But it's a private var atm so maybe someday down the line? In the meantime you can go with the [suggested](https://github.com/unionai-oss/pandera/issues/466#issuecomment-824834333) workaround:

```py
from pandas.api.types import is_numeric_dtype
import pandera as pa
import pandas as pd

is_number = pa.Check(is_numeric_dtype, name="is_number")
schema = pa.DataFrameSchema({"column": pa.Column(checks=is_number)})
schema(pd.DataFrame({"column": [1,2,"a"]}))
```

I see you're using the `SchemaModel` which I'm not very familiar with. I tested this locally and it worked though (w caveat of uncertainty regarding the `Series` annotation:

```py
import pandas as pd
import pandera as pa
from pandera.typing import Series
from pandas.api.types import is_numeric_dtype

class IngestSchema(pa.DataFrameModel):
    column_header: Series

    @pa.check("column_header")
    def check_is_number(cls, column_header: Series):
        return is_numeric_dtype(column_header)

# flags it
IngestSchema(pd.DataFrame({"column_header": [1, 2, "a"]}))

# passes
IngestSchema(pd.DataFrame({"column_header": [1, 2, 3]}))
```

Note that `pa.DataFrameModel` is the updated syntax and `SchemaModel` serves as an alias for it. `SchemaModel` will be deprecated in version 0.20.0 as mentioned in the [docs](https://pandera.readthedocs.io/en/stable/dataframe_models.html).

Comment: Thanks for your workaround. I will implement that!